# GO: cannot find package 'ihelp/pkg/ihelp' in any of

Tags: go

Yesterday I was coding in GO and everything worked well. Today I get the following error message:

```
main.go:10:2: cannot find package "icalculate/pkg/idicalculateive" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/icalculate/pkg/icalculate/algorithm(from $GOROOT)
    /home/ademxkartal/go/src/icalculate/pkg/icalculate/algorithm(from $GOPATH)
```

I have deleted the whole repository and did a git pull with a version from yesterday. Still I cannot compile the go-code. I have tried to compile a simple `hello.go` code and this works. So it seems that the GO Compiler is working in general.

**Any idea for a solution?**

Here is my `go.mod` file:

```
module icalculate

go 1.16
```

here is my module structure (working on Linux-Ubuntu):

```
/calculatorGo
|---- go.mod
|---- go.sum
   |/pkg
      |/icalculate
         |/algorithm
         |---- algorithm.go
```

This is what `go env` prints out:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/ademxkartal/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/ademxkartal/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go-1.10"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go-1.10/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build730659894=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Comment: And: Do not name your modules "foo" but "foo.bar" or "foo.bar.xyz".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but it looks like your `go.mod` is defined for `Go 1.16` but you're trying to run the code with `Go 1.10` dependencies.

I would try to re-sync the dependencies, e.g. remove `go.sum` and run `go mod tidy`.

Comment: thank you! I did a `go version` and I do not know why but I was using `Go 1.10`. I have reinstalled go and with `Go 1.16` everything works again